# How multiple <Directory> sections work in Apache configuration (httpd.conf)?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, .htaccess, httpd.conf

For example, if my '/etc/apache2/httpd.conf' looks like this:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /home>
    AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

The latter `AllowOverride` rule overrides its predecessor for the `/home` directory. That part is clear.

But what happens if my httpd.conf file looks like this?

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com/public>

    AllowOverride None
    Options -MultiViews

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        [...]

    </IfModule>

    [...]

</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/example.com/public/wp-content/cache/minify>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        # WHY IS 'RewriteEngine On' REQUIRED?
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteBase /wp-content/cache/minify/
        RewriteRule [...]

    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Isn't the `RewriteEngine On` in the first `<Directory>` section supposed to apply to the second `<Directory>` section as well, considering that the latter is a sub-directory? But I noticed that I need to add the `RewriteEngine On` rule in the second `<Directory>` section as well.
2. Does this mean that I should also copy all the common rules from the first `<Directory>` section to the second `<Directory>` section? For example, `AllowOverride None`, `Options -MultiViews`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Isn't the `RewriteEngine On` in the first `<Directory>` section supposed to apply to the second `<Directory>` section as well, considering that the latter is a sub-directory? But I noticed that I need to add the `RewriteEngine On` rule in the second `<Directory>` section as well.

[This answer by Jon Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15868802/1071413) on what the `RewriteOptions Inherit` directive does is an eye opener, and indirectly answers this question.

*"Normally, if you have an .htaccess file in a particular sub-directory, any [mod_rewrite configuration settings] in a parent directory are superseded and won't be applied."*

Related Links:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#vhosts

> 2. Does this mean that I should also copy all the common rules from the first `<Directory>` section to the second `<Directory>` section? For example, `AllowOverride None`, `Options -MultiViews`, etc.

No, since all rules for '/var/www/example.com/public' (set in `<Directory /var/www/example.com/public>` section) also apply to its sub-directories, there's no need to copy them again into `<Directory /var/www/example.com/public/wp-content/cache/minify>` section.

Finding this out was easy.

I added this inside the `<Directory /var/www/example.com/public>` section of my httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
    # Set noindex header for robots.txt
    <FilesMatch "robots.txt">
        Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Then dropped a robots.txt file in '/var/www/example.com/public' and '/var/www/example.com/public/wp-content/cache/minify' directories. Both were served with `noindex` HTTP header.